# Rails - Update action ignores validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that has validations password for account creation. However, when a user is updating his password it ignores all validations.

**Users Controller**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name,

      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
      before_save { |user| user.name = name.downcase }
      before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
      before_create { generate_token(:email_token) }

      VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :password, :on => :create, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
      validates :name, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_NAME_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length:  { minimum: 4 }
```

So I tried to remove `:on => :create,`  but when i login i get an error saying password is invalid even though it is. So it wouldnt allow `@user.save!`

**Users controller**

```
  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
validates :password, :presence => {:on => :create}, :confirmation => true, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
```

I think the way you have it written it only executes the whole thing on create and excludes update completely

Comment: Yeah i tried that but when I create a user and change the users email activation token, which is part of registration, and call @user.save! it tells me validation is wrong. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try it with: `:on => [:create, :update]`. But this would mean that any time when a user is saved, you need to enter a password and confirmation, because it is stored as encrypted, so probably cannot be recalled in the user instance. (Otherwise it is not safe.)

Comment: Damn then i can't do it that way. Because I have an email activation token that gets activated when the user checks their email and then user gets saved. It would be annoying to have password and password confirmation on that page.

Comment: You should set up conditional validation on password in case it haven't been changed. Add a custom validator, which handles all the logic you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the encrypted password attribute is named `encrypted_password`

Only validate when we need the password setting.

```
validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }, if: :password_required?

def password_required?
  encrypted_password.blank? || !password.blank?
end
```

Comment: it has before_save :encrypt_password and also when the password is changed to just 2 letters (which should break validations) it still gets encrypted as something lol so. Problem would still exist :(